# how to add a style in django

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I want change the row color in a table whit class, how to put html classes if something happens. And I use bootstrap.

models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Car

def index(request):
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    context = {
        'cars' = cars
    }
    return (request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<div class="table-responsive-md">
    <table class="table tableh-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Color</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for car in cars %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
                <td {if car.color == red } style="background-color: red;"{% endif %}>{{car.color}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
<td {if car.color == red } style="background-color: red;"{% endif %}>{{car.color}}</td>
```

this line is what i want to make work

I`m improving my english, please be patiente :D

Comment: `{% if car.color == 'red' %}`

Comment: Or you can also use `style="background-color: {{ car.color|default:'black' }};"`.

Comment: did not work...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem answer is working for me. 1.) you are missing '%'  in your if condition. 2.) red should be in quotes ( "red" ).

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes here:

1. a template tag, like [**`{% if … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if) is wrapped in curly brackets with percentages (`{% … %}`), you are missing the percentages (`%`); and
2. a string literal is wrapped between quotes, so `'red'`, instead of <s>`red`</s>.

You thus implement this with:

```
<td {% if car.color == 'red' %}style="background-color: red;"{% endif %}>{{car.color}}</td>
```

Comment: @Bodok: based on the error message, that is another `{% if ... %}` condition.

Comment: furhtermore please use *text*, not *images of text*; http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode